# Preventing "Pass the Hash" Attacks in a Web API?

Tags: api, security

I may not be going about this in the best way possible, but as a school project, I'm in a group where we are developing a system to handle checking in and checking out of dorm rooms and handling any charges that may arise because of damages to items in the room. We are digitizing the project and putting in on the web and writing a native iPhone app (part of the assignment, I'd rather just make it a universal web app, but oh well). For the iPhone app, we're putting together a web API but I'm having some doubts about our attempts to keep the API secure.

Our process right now is a call to the API to log in with a username and a password hash, if it was a successful login, an Authentication Token is generated and returned to the iPhone in XML along with various other data. Each subsequent request requires this AuthToken. A user can either sign out, or if there's inactivity for 20 minutes, the AuthToken is destroyed server side. But this leaves the API open for the "Pass The Hash" attack where anybody listening in on the request can get the password hash out of the query string. Anybody with Wireshark and a simple filter can wait for somebody to sign in when everybody would be moving into the dorms and be able to manipulate just about anything.

Every single request is susceptible to the Pass The Hash attack. When logging in, the username and password can be repeated later to obtain a different AuthToken. Not only that, any already generated AuthTokens could be used and the session extended without the real user knowing.

I have thought of the idea of tying the AuthToken to an IP address and rejecting requests that use a valid AuthToken from an alternate IP address, is this reliable or will the iPhone be jumping IP addresses when on the cell network instead of Wifi? I want to give any malicious users a hard time, but obviously not legitimate users.

The project is still in the early stages so now would be the time to make drastic changes to the API like this. Any tips on securing a web API would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to send everything over SSL. That will prevent anyone listening to the wire and sniffing either the password hash or the authentication token.

You should also consider sending a nonce to the client that gets hashed along with the password to prevent replay attacks.

It's also pretty easy to change the authentication token on each request. This prevents both replay and session-fixation. Just make sure the tokens are good random numbers.

Comment: Not convinced that changing tokens would fix anything. If Alice receives tokens W, X, then Y (in that order), and then stops using the service (but doesn't log off), then all Oscar has to do is send Y back to Bob. Bob will think that this is normal in the progression of the communication and send Z back to Oscar, and Oscar just continues Alice's session as though nothing happened. SSL is the only real solution.

Comment: @Stargazer712: Changing tokens doesn't fix *everything*, but it does prevent session fixation and replay. The combination of SSL and token changing is pretty effective. Of course, you **must** use SSL in any case otherwise you might as well not bother with authentication at all.

Comment: I completely forgot about HTTPS. I was buried in the implementation instead of viewing the big picture. Thanks.

Comment: Also, after a little research I learned exactly why HTTPS works to fix this. I did not realize that HTTPS encrypted the URL (query string and all).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTTPS.

Most anything on HTTP is susceptible if you include people using Wireshark. HTTPS encrypts all traffic between the client and the server and will prevent most packet sniffing attacks.